# Question Closed over a valid Tag

Tags: discussion, closed-questions

I posted a question , see

https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1339824/how-to-find-the-next-number?noredirect=1#comment2724983_1339824

and it was immediately down voted and eventually closed.

Here is the thing, there IS an existing and valid tag, called [pattern-recognition](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/pattern-recognition)

that states [in the tag-excerpt and the tag-wiki](https://math.stackexchange.com/tags/pattern-recognition/info)

From a sample of small samples of mathematical objects, conjecture a common pattern to all of them, THIS includes "guess the next terms in the sequence", and also mentions to check the online directory of sequences ( I did).

So here it is, that description is literally exactly what my question was.

And it was closed, so should that tag be taken away? Because if using that tag and basically asking a question that is exactly what is described, and it is closed, then how is it valid?

Comment: The tag itself has been previously discussed [here](http://meta.math.stackexchange.com/questions/6588/what-is-the-purpose-of-the-pattern-recognition-tag) with inconclusive results. But it is commonly used as described in the tag-wiki, so you tagged your question correctly.

Comment: Whether this type of questions is allowed was previously discussed [here](http://meta.math.stackexchange.com/questions/924/guess-the-next-number-guess-the-relation-etc). (And probably in several other discussions.)

Comment: On puzzling.SE a tag called [number-sequence](http://puzzling.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/number-sequence) exists. So it might be worth considering asking your question there.

Comment: We also have tags [tag:physics] and [tag:philosophy], it doesn't mean that anything related to physics or philosophy is on-topic here. We also need tags to categorize existing, off-topic questions. Using the fact that a tag exists to argue that your question is on-topic is not a valid argument.

Comment: FYI: The question is even deleted.

Comment: @najjb it seems to be a valid argument seeing as the tag describes exactly what the user had posted

Comment: @Quality Did you read my whole comment...?

Comment: Yes I did, and your whole argument only holds if you are willing to accept that the site includes tags that should never be used..

Comment: @Quality Nope. If you have a mathematical question that has ties to physics (its motivation comes from physics, for example), then using the physics tag is fine. But the existence of the tag does not mean that every question related to physics is on-topic here.

Comment: @najib I have a feeling you didn't even read the question by the user at all . The tag in question literally stated "questions of the form" and then continued to say exactly the type of question the user posted

Comment: Najib, I understand perfectly what you are saying. I don't see how you can seriously not understand the point. Did you read what I wrote or not? How can you even disagree if you read it at all. The tag is not physics, it is   a tag that DIRECTLY described WORD for WORD the exact type of problem he asked. By your logic, NO question can be used with that tag.

Comment: Ie, the tag says ( If you actually read it) [sic] "questions that are similar to given some random sequence of numbers, conjecture some pattern about them". Now, look at the question. It was exactly, given this sequence of numbers, conjecture a pattern about them. Do you understand this? I think it is not a matter of mathematical ability to understand this as you are obviously much superior in that manner, but I really don't see how you canont see this point of view

Comment: If this discussion is to turn into a shouting match, I'm not interested anymore.

Comment: No thats okay, I did not mean to seem as such. I understand your point as well, I am just saying it seems that you really aren't paying attention to what I even wrote/ you did not address that point

Answer (score 11):

I don't know why such a permissive summary was given for this tag. I typed in an extra line, pointing out that a question that asks to "guess the next number in the sequence" and gives no mathematical context will generally be closed quickly.

Meanwhile, I recommend [http://www.amazon.com/The-Book-Numbers-John-Conway/dp/038797993X](http://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/038797993X)  which shows some legitimate mathematical questions of this type, and ways to solve them.

Answer (score 6):

There is an [algebra-precalculus](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/algebra-precalculus) tag, and yet we close questions about algebra too - for the same reason, too: *Your questions lacks context.* It doesn't tell us where this sequence comes from, or what significance would be in knowing an answer. Just telling us, "...we could say that any number was next, but this is not what is expected." does not help us get an answer - and telling us "I have tried really anything" does not tell us what you tried (which could give us an idea of what form you expect an answer to take). [OEIS](https://oeis.org/) and [this answer](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/819382) basically cover the entire mathematical content of your question - refer to either one, but posting a new question is not productive and might as well be closed (possibly as a duplicate of any earlier one asking about any finite sequence with no clear origin)

Comment: This one is closed as "not about mathematics", not "lacking context".

Comment: @1999 Irrespective of the close reason, I think it could be on-topic were context added - even if this is a particular case where a lack of context also creates a lack of any mathematical content.